# AVFoundation stop after successful scan

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am building a QR Code Scanner App with Swift 3(Xcode 8.1) for iOS 10 and I am using the AVFoundation Framework. Does anybody know how to stop scanning after a successful scan and reactivate the Scanner after something like tapping the screen or whatever?

EDIT:
Here is a snippet of my code (no code of what happens with the return value):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class QRCodeViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?

let supportedBarCodes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession?.addInput(input)

        let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

        captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

        captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedBarCodes

        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

        captureSession?.startRunning()


        qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

        if case (qrCodeFrameView?.isHidden)! = true       {
            qrCodeFrameView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            qrCodeFrameView?.layer.borderWidth = 2
            view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView!)
            view.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView!)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
        return
    }

}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
        return
    }




    let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject


    if supportedBarCodes.contains(metadataObj.type) {

        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds
  print(metadataObj.stringValue)

}
```

Comment: can you share some piece of code ?

Comment: @MuseerAnsari Added Code to the question

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if you have any issue, Thank Yoou!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your delegate method

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
    qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
    return
}

let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject


if supportedBarCodes.contains(metadataObj.type) {

    let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
    qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds
    print(metadataObj.stringValue)

    // Stop capture session 
    videoPreviewLayer?.isHidden = true
    qrCodeFrameView?.isHidden = true
    self.captureSession?.stopRunning()
}
```

Comment: Welcome and happy coding  :)